# Mathematical Equation Notation

Tags: notation

I came a cross some equations when working on a project and unfortunately, the notation is not clear to me. I would highly appreciate if someone could clarify this.
Below are the two equations:

1. In the first equation, I am not sure what exactly the vertical line at the end with the $\theta^{(t)}$ is suppose to mean.
   $$
   θ^{(t)}_a=θ^{(t)}−\sum_{i=1}^ma^{(t)}_i∇_θL_i(\theta,D_i)|_{θ^{(t)}}
   $$
2. The second one, I don't understand at all.
   $$
   ∇_{w_i}L_{V_j}(Alg(θ^*_w,V_{S_j}),V^Q_j) = \frac{∂L_{V_j}}{∂Alg(θ^∗_W,V^S_j)}\frac{∂Alg(θ^∗_W,V^S_j)}{∂θ_W}\frac{dθ_W}{d_{w_i}}
   $$
   with $L_{V_j}(φ) := L(φ, V^Q_j)$.

In the second equation, it is clear to me, that we take the gradients w.r.t. $w_i$. But unfortunately, I do not understand the first two fractions and also not why it says $dθ_W$ in the numerator of the last fraction.

Many thanks!

Comment: Usually "evaluating" a function of $\theta$ at point $\theta^{(t)}$

Comment: See [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/who-introduced-the-notation-y-x-a)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\nabla G(W(x(t),y), Z) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial W}\cdot \frac{\partial W}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
This is an application of the chain rule.

I would suggest investing some time into partial differential equations, especially if you are working with these optimisation (ML) algorithms from "first" principles.

The `|` means evaluated the function at a particular point. A simple example is
$$
\left.F(x)\right|_{x=a} = F(a)
$$
Taking this to your problem, we will compute the result of the derivatives and then evaluate by inserting $\theta = \theta^{(t)}$

Comment: Please edit your answer to overtly include the | portion, even though it is in comments.  At some point in the future, an author of a comment (where the author is not you) might for some reason delete the comment, hence losing the rest of the answer.  Likewise, some other author of a comment might provide a conflicting or wrong answer to the | portion of the question, which would lead the reader astray, hence you overtly stating the | portion of the answer here in your answer overtly calls out which of the (future) two | portions of the answer that appear in comments.

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER Ok will do!